# how to use a bash function defined in your .bashrc with find -exec

Tags: bash, function, find, exec

my .bashrc has the following function

```
function myfile {
 file $1
}
export -f myfile
```

it works fine when i call it directly

```
rajesh@rajesh-desktop:~$ myfile out.ogv 
out.ogv: Ogg data, Skeleton v3.0
```

it does not work when i try to invoke it through exec

```
rajesh@rajesh-desktop:~$ find ./ -name *.ogv -exec myfile {} \;
find: `myfile': No such file or directory
```

is there a way to call bash script functions with exec?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

#### Update:

Thanks for the response Jim.

But that's exactly what I wanted to avoid in the first place, since I have lot of utility functions defined in my bash scripts, I wanted to use them with other useful commands like find -exec.

I totally see your point though, find can run executables, it has no idea that the argument passed is function defined in a script.

I will get the same error when I try to exec is on bash prompt.

```
$ exec myfile out.ogv
```

I was hoping that there may be some neat trick that exec could be given some hypothetical command like "bash -myscriptname -myfunctionname".

I guess I should try to find some way to create a bash script on the fly and run it with exec.

Comment: This isn't a forum. Please don't post responses as answers to the question unless they are.

Comment: The reason I am doing is that add comment does not allow you to add code.

Comment: But editing your own original post allows you to add as much code as you want and is more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get bash to run a function by putting the command into bash's StdIn:

```
bash$ find ./ -name *.ogv -exec echo myfile {} \; | bash
```

The command above will work for your example **but** you need to take note of the fact that all of the '`myfile...`' commands are generated at once and sent to a single bash process.

Comment: This also looks good. It worked in my case as expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

```
find ./ -name *.ogv -exec bash -c 'myfile {}' \;
```

Comment: You should probably quote the filename: `bash -c 'myfile "{}"'`.

Comment: Pretty sure that bash command won't expand the variable as you have it. I think it should be `bash -c 'myfile "$0"' {} \;`

Answer (score 7):

I managed to run it perhaps more elegantly as:

```
function myfile { ... }
export -f myfile
find -name out.ogv -exec bash -c '"$@"' myfile myfile '{}' \;
```

Notice that `myfile` is given twice. The first one is the `$0` parameter of the script (and in this case it can be basically anything). The second one is the name of the function to run.

Answer (score 6):

```
$ cat functions.bash
#!/bin/bash

function myecho { echo "$@"; }
function myfile { file "$@"; }
function mycat { cat "$@"; }

myname=`basename $0`
eval ${myname} "$@"
$ ln functions.bash mycat
$ ./mycat /etc/motd
Linux tallguy 2.6.32-22-core2 ...
$ ln functions.bash myfile
$ myfile myfile
myfile: Bourne-Again shell script text executable
$ ln functions.bash myecho
$ myecho does this do what you want\?
does this do what you want?
$
```

where, of course, the functions can be a tad more complex than my examples.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think `find` can do this, since it's the `find` command itself that's executing
the command, and not the shell you're currently running...so bash functions or aliases
won't work there.  If you take your function definition and turn it into a separate
bash script called `myfile`, make it executable, and install it on your path somewhere,
`find` should do the right thing with it.

Answer (score 3):

even simpiler

```
function myfile { echo $* ; }
export -f myfile

find . -type f -exec bash -c 'myfile "{}"'  \;
```

Comment: This works really well, thank you! What does the export "-f" do? As soon as I added it after my function, it worked! Before I only had "export myfile"

Comment: the -f means to export the item as a function instead of as a variable

Comment: I just tried this again. it won't work from the command line (I suspect the shell shock patch), but if I put all this in a file it does work.

Comment: I tracked down a pre Shell Shocked version of Bash. it works on the command line for  that version. Post Shell Shocked you need to do it from a script (why?). @KevinBuchs please reconsider your down vote.

Comment: last up date, it does work from the command if you are using compatible versions of bash. my login shell bash is a different version from the bash in my path and they didn't work together.  So it will work from the command line if the bash versions are compatible.

Answer (score 2):

Child shell scripts seems to keep the parent functions so you could do a script similar to this one:

'runit.sh'

```
#! /bin/bash

"$@"
```

then do `find -name out.ogv -exec ./runit.sh myfile '{}' \;`
and it works! :)

Comment: Thanks Joao. This looks like very clever and elegant solution. Little issue was that I had to source my script first to run myfile function e.g. I borrowed from your suggestion and made my runint.sh as follows

    #!/bin/bash
    script_name=$1
    func_name=$2
    func_arg=$3
    source $script_name
    $func_name $func_arg

    $ find ./ -name *.ogv -exec ./runit.sh ~/.bashrc myfile {} \;
    ./out.ogv: Ogg data, Skeleton v3.0

Otherwise I was getting

    $ find ./ -name *.ogv -exec ./runit.sh myfile {} \;
    ./runit.sh: 1: myfile: not found

Any thanks a lot.

Comment: Rather than sourcing the script from runit.sh, you can have the script export the function (`export -f myfile`) before using it.

Comment: I assumed he was doing it in his `.bashrc`. Thats why it should have worked, right?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Joao. This looks like very clever and elegant solution. Little issue was that I had to source my script first to run myfile function e.g. I borrowed from your suggestion and made my runint.sh as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
script_name=$1
func_name=$2
func_arg=$3
source $script_name
$func_name $func_arg
```

Now I can run it as follows

```
$ find ./ -name *.ogv -exec ./runit.sh ~/.bashrc myfile {} \;
./out.ogv: Ogg data, Skeleton v3.0
```

Otherwise I was getting

```
$ find ./ -name *.ogv -exec ./runit.sh myfile {} \;
./runit.sh: 1: myfile: not found
```

Anyway thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This oneliner should do in my case:

```
find . -name *.ogv -exec bash -c 'myfile {}' \;
```